# Run Batch File in VC++

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++, file-io

I want to move file using batch file , for that i do use below code the process seems to get executed successfully , but the file do not get transferred. Is anything wrong with this code?

```
    STARTUPINFO osi;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &osi, sizeof(osi) );
    osi.cb = sizeof(capinfo);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    wchar_t cmd[8192];
    wchar_t ocmd[8192];
    char ocmd1[8192];
    swprintf_s(ocmd,sizeof(ocmd),L"%s\\%s.bat",capodd->templocation,capodd->wcurrentoutput);
    sprintf_s(ocmd1,sizeof(ocmd1),"%ls\\%s.bat",capodd->templocation,capodd->currentoutput);
    FILE * tempbat = fopen(ocmd1,"w");

    swprintf_s(cmd,8192,L"move %s\\%s.mp4 %s\\%s.mp4",capodd->templocation,capodd->wcurrentoutput,capodd->destination,capodd->wcurrentoutput);
    fprintf(tempbat,"%ls\n",cmd);
    //swprintf_s(cmd,8192,L"move %s\\%s.txt %s\\%s.txt",capodd->templocation,capodd->currentoutput,capodd->destination,capodd->currentoutput);
    //fprintf(tempbat,"%ls\n",cmd);
    //fprintf(tempbat,"del %ls\n",ocmd);
    fclose(tempbat);
    swprintf_s(cmd,sizeof(cmd),L"cmd /c %s",ocmd);
    // just for fun, sleep for twice my latency to make sure the other half of the graph has started
    Sleep(1000 *2); // of course, this means our overlap better be within 2x of the periodicity

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,cmd,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&osi,&pi)) {
        fprintf(capodd->c_pF,"couldn't execute copy %d\n",GetLastError());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems in your code:
1- `osi.cb = sizeof(capinfo);` should be changed to `osi.cb = sizeof(osi);`
2- Using `sizeof()` in `swprintf_s` is not correct. You should use `_countof()` instead of it, or you can omit `sizeof()` when using static array.
I tested this code and there was no other problems.

Comment: thanks @A. Danesh for your reply, actually issue was that file was in use by another process and bcoz of that , it was not transferring file.